# String to Object in Python

Tags: python, string, object

I need to be able to convert any string representation of an object back into its original state on another computer. I will use the class, A, as my example:

```
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = "test"
            self.name = "Bob"

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.data) + " " + str(self.name)
```

An object of class A must be able to be recreated on a separate computer. So if a separate computer received ("A", "memberData memberName"), it could convert this into an object of class A. I need this to be possible with any user defined object. Preferably I would like the user to only have to create a toString() and toObject() method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking at ways of serialising objects; this is a very standard problem. `pickle` is the standard solution, and you should look into it first. If you want to make a class pickleable, you need to define some custom methods on it, and ensure the module in which it is defined can be found on both the source and destination computers. Then you can `pickle.dumps(obj)` which will return a string, and `pickle.loads(my_str)` to rebuild the object.

Other options include `marshal` (low-level) and `json` (standard for web data).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serialise and deserialise python objects, [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) has already been pointed out a a very good, and standard, solution. Python also uses [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) to obtain string representations of objects that **could be** used to construct an equivalent object. In your case, the simplest way would be to add `data` and `name` as constructor arguments, and define a `__repr__` function using `repr` of the data members:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data, name):
        self.data = data
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%s,%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, repr(self.data), repr(self.name))
```

Then you can do

```
a = A('test', 'Bob')
a_repr = repr(a)
a_copy = eval(a_repr)
```

and so on. Obviously this will become difficult for larger, more complex classes.

Answer (score 2):

eval() works for me

```
    s='[{'name':'bob','org':"happy's place"}]'
    obj=eval(s)
    print(obj[0]['name'])
```

will return 'bob'

Answer (score 1):

pickle and shelve can be useful. E.g.

```
import shelve

a = A();

db = shelve.open('myclasses')
db['a'] = a
db.close()
```

This will create file myclasses that will store your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle seems to be the right choice.

You might want to use the `dump()` and `load()` methods to save and get object from string.

```
# The object to pickle
object_pi = myDict    
# Dump the data as string to file 
pickle.dump(object_pi, filename)

# The file with serialized data to retrieve
fileHandler = open(filename, 'r') 
# The data is stored into my_object variable
my_object = pickle.load(fileHandler)
```

Source link: [snip2code - Using Pickle To Save Objects In Python](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11808)